# jQuery Getting SPAN value with a specific Class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors

Alright. I've `span` elements like below in my page.

```
    <span class="Jens">Bill Gates</span>
    <span class="noJens">Martin Reid</span>
    <span class="Jens">Jeff Bezos</span>
    <span class="Jens">Mark Zuckerberg</span>
    <span class="noJens">Nameless Dude</span>
    <span class="Jens">Jack Ma</span>
    <span class="Jens">Larry Ellison</span>
```

I wanted to get all span values with the class name as `Jens` & need to separate the values with some space or break.

I managed to get the values by giving the following code. But how to separate each entry with a space or a break?

```
$("span[class='Jens']").text(); //Outputs Bill GatesJeff BezosMark ZuckerbergJack MaLarry Ellison
```

I can achieve desired output by iterating over each elements. But Is there a way I can separate each entry with a space or `\n` in a single statement like above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get them comma seprated using:

```
$('.Jens').map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get().join();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/57rwax84/)**

For joining them with `\n` pass parameter `\n` in join method:

> Syntax for join: array.join(separator)

```
$('.Jens').map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get().join("\n")
```

**[Working Demo with \n](http://jsfiddle.net/x56ozo85/)**

Comment: really? ever heard of the `.` selector for classes?

Comment: @SteveFenton I commented on another version with syntax error.

Comment: @SteveFenton yeah, so write `span.classname`?

Comment: dfsq is correct. quotes in selector were incorrect.

Comment: @Alex Also matches `<span class="Jens noJens">`. What OP has is fine

Comment: @MilindAnantwar It worked. ThankYou..:) But any other method than a callback?

Comment: i personally dont see this in the ops question, specific class name does not say only this class name, but okay :)

Comment: @JensonMJohn: you need to use .each to iterate over span and then push them in array one by one. which is not feasible way of doing it.

Comment: @Alex, it is here - quoted from original question: `$("span[class='Jens']").text();`.

Comment: Ive seen that in the question, but still never mind (: